# Google sheets forecast function, nonsensical result

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I can't deduce my error in using google sheets forecast function.  I have a range of values by date and am trying to forecast values on future dates.  I used the Forecast function, specifying the next value cell, and using the date cells as the y axis and the test values as the x axis.  Although my test values are between 187 and 194, my forecast result is 44320.43601.  I am clearly making some error in the formula, but I cannot figure out what it is.

Spreadsheet is here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Y2wmKzIjAv0a3zEa-ITjBPqiO9jMSglGwN2o1V5BYjc/edit?ts=5e8a095d#gid=0

Comment: 44320.43601 is forcasted datevalue

Answer (score 1):

should be:

```
=FORECAST(A20, B1:B19, A1:A19)
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thank you player0.  That appears to work.  Why is it a20?  I want to understand the logic.

Comment: well, it needs to be A20 because you are trying to predict value in B based on date dimension (which is in your case just one day ahead). think of it as it would some kind of straight line on paper - start of that line is your first date eg A1 and end of that line is A20. now plot rest of the dates in between with the correct ratio of distance. then you take your B column values and plot them next to the correct dates.

Comment: (for simplicity of imagination, instead your B values use simple numeric scale 1,2,3,4,5,6,7.... - so its only logical that 20th value will be 20 if difference in days is always 1 day and difference in values is always increased by +1) << and that's pretty much what forecasting is just a bit more complex